# How to show another Activity in background when progress dialog is appeared?

Tags: android, view

I am developing an Android app. There is an `Activity` which showing `Button`.
When a button is pressed `ProgressDialog` should appear and behind `ProgressDialog` there should be another Activity that should open.
I want activity other then this Activity in which button is. How can I achieve this?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.gamemenu);


    TextView tvStart = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.start);
    //TextView tvSettings = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.settings);
    TextView tvAbout = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.instruction);
    TextView tvExit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.exit);

    tvStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    //tvSettings.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvAbout.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvExit.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.start:

        ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(StartMenu.this);  
        pd=ProgressDialog.show(StartMenu.this,"Loading","Please Wait",false);  
        Handler handler=new Handler();
           Runnable gotologin=new Runnable() 
           {
           public void run() 
           {
            startActivity(new Intent(StartMenu.this,AndroidGame.class));
            finish();
           }
           };
           handler.postDelayed(gotologin, 3000);       
           pd.dismiss();    
        //   finish();     
          break;
     // Intent iStart = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AndroidGame.class );
    //  startActivity(iStart);
    //  break;

    /*case R.id.settings:
        Intent iSettings = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameSettings.class );
        startActivity(iSettings);
        break;*/

    case R.id.instruction:
        Intent inInstructions = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Instructions.class );
        startActivity(inInstructions);
        break;

    case R.id.exit:
        ((Activity)v.getContext()).finish();
        //this.finish();

        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the `ProgressDialog` in this way.But,I don't think this progressDialog would been seen as the new Activity would be loaded on the screen before you can show the `ProgressDialog`.

```
ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(ActivityName.this);  
Button n=new Button(ActivityName.this);  
n.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
@Override  
public void onClick(View v) {  

       pd=ProgressDialog.show(ActivityName.this,"Loading","Please Wait",false);  
       Intent i=new Intent(ActivityName.this,TargetActivityName.class)  
       startActivity(i);  
       pd.dismiss();    
       finish();     
   }  
});
```

If you want to show a `ProgressDialog` on click for Some time for your requirement,you can achieve that using `Handler`'s that would load the the new Activity after some predecided time.

A sample example which would hold the `ProgressDialog` for **3 Sec** is as followed:

```
ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(ActivityName.this);  
Button n=new Button(ActivityName.this);  
n.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
@Override  
public void onClick(View v) {  

   pd=ProgressDialog.show(ActivityName.this,"Loading","Please Wait",false);  

   Handler handler=new Handler();
   Runnable gotologin=new Runnable() 
   {
   public void run() 
   {
    startActivity(new Intent(ActivityName.this, TargetActivityName.class));
    finish();
   }
   };
   handler.postDelayed(gotologin, 3000);       
   pd.dismiss();    
   finish();     
  }  
});
```

## Required Answer:

```
ProgressDialog pd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.gamemenu);


    pd=new ProgressDialog(StartMenu.this);   // Edited here


    TextView tvStart = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.start);
    //TextView tvSettings = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.settings);
    TextView tvAbout = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.instruction);
    TextView tvExit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.exit);

    tvStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    //tvSettings.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvAbout.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvExit.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.start:

         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
           public void run() {
              pd=ProgressDialog.show(StartMenu.this,"Loading","Please Wait",false);  
              Handler handler=new Handler();
               Runnable gotologin=new Runnable() 
               {
                public void run() 
                {
                  startActivity(new Intent(StartMenu.this,AndroidGame.class));
                  finish();
                }
               };
              handler.postDelayed(gotologin, 3000);       
              pd.dismiss();    
              finish();  

            }
      });
      //     break;
     // Intent iStart = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AndroidGame.class );
    //  startActivity(iStart);
    //  break;

    /*case R.id.settings:
        Intent iSettings = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameSettings.class );
        startActivity(iSettings);
        break;*/

    case R.id.instruction:
        Intent inInstructions = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Instructions.class );
        startActivity(inInstructions);
        break;

    case R.id.exit:
        ((Activity)v.getContext()).finish();
        //this.finish();

        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Im using above code but progressdialog is not appearing. Is it due to Background image in view?

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using in the Question Section.That might make things easy to understand.

Comment: Is the above posted code in the onCreate method??Can you post the code of the whole activity??There is a sure problem of context in your code.

Comment: I have posted the Whole Answer.You check it by copy and replacing the whole thing that you have posted here.And after tell me the output.Ok.

Comment: it showing error multiple marker on this line At override public void run.

Comment: Ok..can you tell me the JDK version in which you have developed the App.??

Comment: You can find it by right clicking on the project and clicking the properties and their,see the Java Compiler Section,and then make JDK compliance to 1.6 if it is not.

Comment: Did You got the required Answer ?

Answer (score 3):

You cant load another activity in background as on above of a window which belongs to the previous activity.

In your case, I would suggest you to load your second activity when a button is clicked. However, in your second activity, show the required progress dialog as long as you want.

Comment: in second activity where is popup should be shown? when it loads and how can i kept pause the activity?

Comment: You may show a popup in **onCreate** of second activity, and if there's some data binding etc. which takes time to initialize then I would suggest you to make use of **AsyncTask** with in the same activity and dismiss the progress dialog in **onPostExecute** of the AsyncTak